# OpenID, how open is it?

Tags: openid

Maybe I'm confusing the issue. I understand, using OpenID, people can log into my site using either Yahoo / Google / Other providers without signing up a username/password on my site. Great.

The issue for me though is how do I query Yahoo network information of a user when the user signed into my site using Google OpenID?  I mean I don't see a connection between Google and Yahoo. It sort of defeats the purpose of OpenID, no? (As both Google and Yahoo are OpenID providers and yet, they can't talk to each other for the same user. Then, what good does it do to have a "universal log in"?)

I actually see FlickR, you can (part of Yahoo Network), you can sign in using Google ID, but the issue is, I already have a Yahoo ID, how do you connect my Google OpenID with my existing Yahoo ID?

My idea of a "Universal Login" is that it doesn't matter which provider I registered my account with, this login can be used on any OpenID provider. If I have an existing account, I can hook it up or replace with this exiting ID. From then on and forward, I can get my information anywhere as long as I login using this "Universal Login"

A bit confused. Hope someone can clarify the issue for me.

Thanks

Comment: Is @CodingHorror in the house?  Paging @CodingHorror ...

Comment: Is this a programming question?

Comment: @amelvin, what do you mean? 

@Gabe, it's not a programming question (but I want to ask programmers), because I think I might misunderstood certain aspect of "openid" and how is it really being used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenID is an open specification. It define an interface between a provider and a consumer that is identical[1] between all providers and all consumers.

It's not about connecting your Yahoo identity with your Google identity, it's about letting you to identify yourself by any[2] of your OpenID identities (Yahoo, Google, etc as provider) on many other websites (as consumer) instead of creating new user-accounts and remembering many passwords.

Yahoo and Google are both provider (not consumers).

[1] Almost identical, because they may support additional extensions.

[2] Or optionally some.

Comment: JohnS. Great. "Yahoo and Google are both provider and none are consumers" clarified it. I confused the issue of Logging v.s say "Social Security #"  where a Government agency can can pull up my tax, employment history, dmv records, bank records, etc. As "none are consumers".

Answer (score 2):

This is Jeff Attwood's recent explanation of why SO uses openid - on his Coding Horror blog.

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/11/your-internet-drivers-license.html

Comment: Thanks Amelvin. Hmm, I guess he's talking about the "log in" part, but his example is not that great. True, I can use my Debt card to "login" a foreign ATM machine, to get cash. But their ATM machines are actually TALKING to my bank. I will see a bill plus service charge directly out of my bank. Using his logic, I will use OpenID (the debt card), log into a foreign site (get into foreign ATM), retrieve contents of the site (retrieve cash out of that ATM). There is no talking with the site I sign up with my OpenID. If ATM does not talk to my bank, I'll be a billionaire now.

Comment: Getting a bit abstract now. The ATM model requires the transaction to be posted back to the OpenId provider (the card issuing company) so that the provider can stop you becoming a billionaire.  So I think I agree because the OpenId provider shouldn't matter.

Comment: Yeah, in this case, i will rethink about using OpenID and just go directly with OAuth for each individual vendor as OpenID simply defeats the purpose. Provide OAuth, I'm actually acting like an ATM and retrieve contents on behave of the provider (bank). The service charge in this case is ads on my site :)

Answer (score 1):

I hear two questions:

**1.  How do I get info about a user who uses an OpenID to access my site?**
OpenID provides a number of libraries for that.  Just take your pick:
http://openid.net/developers/libraries/

**2.  How do I associate existing accounts with an OpenID?**
Some providers will do this for you (Google).  Either way, you will have to do it either at the provider end, or at the acceptor end, I don't know of any way to merge existing accounts.

EG.  Associate two accounts with a user on one site (your Yahoo ID and your OpenID).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. So basically, this is no different than saying "Log-in using a login web services" from each individual provider. Being OpenID standard, maybe the only advantage to coder is 80% of the code is similar. Other than, no other benefits?